# unable to log into 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I have accidentally deleted some of the files from usr and apt folders and all dot(hidden forlders). when I try to log in it's opening a blank desktop without anything displayed and when I tried to enter root with "cd user" it is saying "no such file or directory". Please help me to recover my account back.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command: `sudo apt purge ubuntu-desktop; sudo apt install ububtu-desktop`

Should reinstall the desktop environment. Check back with results when you got it! (Also maybe a picture if you can get one).

There is also some guide out there if you Google something like `ubuntu add user command line`.